# Is there a way to reduce indention in PhpStorm's Project folder view?

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm displays the folder structure in a classical way:

```
Project
----Folder1
--------Subfolder1
------------Subsubfolder1
----------------FilenameIActuallyCareFor.php
```

What I usually see is

```
Project
----Folder1
--------Subfolder1
------------Subsubfol
----------------Filen
```

unless I expend that window to a size that I hardly see my code. Is there a way to reduce that indention?

Comment: I realise that windows is scrollable, but seeing filenames without knowing where they are istn't that much better.

Comment: You can change view to "changed files": https://i.imgur.com/U1RLecH.jpg or use double shift to find what you need. Or use breadcrumbs navigation: https://i.imgur.com/5t0e3LS.jpg

Comment: One more useful button: https://i.imgur.com/kDTfnFi.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's GUI Theme (a.k.a. Look&Feel in Java apps) dependent .. so should be "No". You may try another GUI Theme though.

In any case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158781 -- watch that and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

As a possible alternative -- try using **Navigation Bar** (the one under Main menu) -- it allows you to see where the currently selected/active file is located as well as allows to navigate through the project/file structure (other folders) and open files straight from there etc.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigation-bar.html